# Difference between 'process default' and 'process full'?

Tags: ssms, ssas-tabular

What is the difference between ‘Process Default’ and ‘Process Full’?

[image]

When I do ‘Process Default’ it works fine, but if I use ‘process full’ I get this error?
[image]

Why is this??

Answer (score 0):

See doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/process-database-table-or-partition-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_process_db

**Default** won't load data unless it has to. If you process a newly created object, or a database that has unprocessed objects, it will load that data. But if the data is loaded already, then SSAS won't touch it.

**Full** loads everything and recalculates everything every time.

Full is failing for you as the message states, because of a login issue. You need to update the credentials being used.

Answer (score 0):

When only the meta data changes, choose **Process Default**

When the data changes, choose **Process Full**

Pro tip: Always use the "Script" button and execute the code, you'll get more debug information when it fails.